# How can I stop the endless output in Unity console?

Tags: c#, unity

I want to print the sum of two numbers, but only when I press the enter key. Pressing any other key should give me the message "Invalid Key". 
Now the output I am getting is an endless loop of "Invalid key", until I press another button.

[image: This is my log, with the "Invalid Key" message being repeated.]

How do I only produce the output when I press a key?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class LearningScript : MonoBehaviour {

    public int number1 = 5;
    public int number2 = 10;
    public bool condition;
    public int answers;

    void Update()
    {  
        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.Return))
            condition = true;
        else
            condition = false;

        if (condition)
            Debug.Log (answers);
        else
            Debug.Log ("INVALID KEY");
    }

    void Start()
    {
        answers = addTwonumbers (number1, number2);         
    }

    int addTwonumbers(int num1,int num2)
    {
        int result = num1 + num2;
        return result;
    }           
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modify your `Update` to look like below:

```
void Update ()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Return))
    {
        condition = true;
        Debug.Log(answers);
    }
    else if (Input.anyKeyDown)
    {
        condition = false;
        Debug.Log("INVALID KEY");
    }
}
```

Printing the "Invalid Key" message without a condition is causing the message to print in every frame, whenever you are not pressing the enter key.

Also use `GetKeyDown` to avoid multiple calls from a single press that spans multiple frames.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. That's what I get for writing out an answer before waking up properly. ;)

Comment: Been there. ;) ...